# Which form of Jeffrey's prior can be used for a three-parameter distribution?

Tags: bayesian, prior, fisher-information, jeffreys-prior

Let *X* be a random variable which follows a distribution, say *S* with parameters *a*, *b* and *c*. Knowing that or Assuming that *a*, *b* and *c* are independent of one another, which one is reasonable to do?

a) Is it okay to find joint Jeffrey's prior as the product of three Jeffrey's prior (for *a*, *b* and *c*)?

b) Is it better to use the square root of determinant of a 3x3 Fisher's Infromation matrix?

Even for a normal distribution with two unknown parameters, joint Jeffrey's prior based on the product of two Jeffrey's prior (mu and sigma) yields a slighly different prior than the one based on the determinant of a 2x2 Fisher's Information matrix.

Comment: I cannot give a full answer, but there are several examples of Jeffreys' priors in multiparameter families that do not perform well, so that, in practice, a) is, to my knowledge, indeed advocated in some cases although it is not actually Jeffreys' prior.

Comment: An even more appropriate prior is the reference prior of Bernardo (1979) that separates the parameter of interest from the nuisance parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jeffreys prior for a three parameter model is the square root of the determinant of the Fisher information matrix.

If you take the product of individual Jeffreys priors, this is called the "independence Jeffreys prior".

Here is an example of an independence Jeffreys prior for 3-parameter models:

[On the independence Jeffreys prior for skew-symmetric models](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.spl.2013.11.012)

In many cases, this yields to a better prior as it reduces the dependence between parameters. See:

[A catalogue of noninformative priors](http://www.stats.org.uk/priors/noninformative/YangBerger1998.pdf)